# How to call WSAStartup() in C# (on Windows Phone 7)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-7, native-methods, wsastartup

Goal: getting a Windows Phone 7 name (like, "My Windows Phone").

Lead: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andypennell/archive/2013/11/09/getting-the-name-of-your-windows-phone-8-device.aspx

The above code is provided as C++, and I would like to change it to C#. One reason is because I only have Visual Studio 2012 Express and it doesn't allow me to use C++ together with a Windows Phone project, and I already bought VS2013, can't afford VS2012 just for this. Another reason is it's more than 150 files of dependencies in C++, that's too much code!

So, my first attempt: (inspired by http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/.NET/Q_21014265.html)

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct WSAData
    {
        public short wVersion;
        public short wHighVersion;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 257)]
        public string szDescription;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 129)]
        public string szSystemStatus;
        public short iMaxSockets;
        public short iMaxUdpDg;
        public int lpVendorInfo;
    }

    [DllImport("wsock32.dll")]
    internal static extern int WSAStartup(
          [In] short wVersionRequested,
          [Out] out WSAData lpWSAData
          );

    [DllImport("wsock32.dll")]
    internal static extern int WSACleanup();

    public static void Test()
    {
        WSAData dummy;
        WSAStartup(0x0002, out dummy);
        // TODO: more stuff
        WSACleanup();
    }
```

It fails on `WSAStartup(0x0002, out dummy);` with Exception:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.MethodAccessException' occurred in MyLibrary.dll
>
> Additional information: Attempt to access the method failed: MyLibrary.WSAStartup(System.Int16, .WSAData&)

And my second attempt: (inspired by [Convert service name to port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457977/convert-service-name-to-port))

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct WSAData
    {
        public short version;
        public short highVersion;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 257)]
        public string description;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 129)]
        public string systemStatus;
        public short maxSockets;
        public short maxUdpDg;
        public IntPtr vendorInfo;
    }

    internal static class NativeMethods
    {
        [DllImport("Ws2_32.dll")]
        public static extern Int32 WSAStartup(short wVersionRequested, ref WSAData wsaData);

        [DllImport("Ws2_32.dll")]
        public static extern Int32 WSACleanup();
    }

    public static void Test()
    {
        WSAData dummy = new WSAData();
        NativeMethods.WSAStartup(0x0202, ref dummy);
        // TODO: more stuff
        NativeMethods.WSACleanup();
    }
```

It fails on `NativeMethods.WSAStartup(0x0202, ref dummy);` with Exception:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.MethodAccessException' occurred in MyLibrary.dll
>
> Additional information: Attempt to access the method failed: MyLibrary+NativeMethods.WSAStartup(System.Int16, .WSAData&)

Any advice to make it work on a WP7 device?

[edit: [this post](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/i-n/internet/network/article.php/c3431/Get-hostname-and-ip-address-of-local-computer.htm) also suggests the possibility of version 0x0101 to use WSAStartup()]

Comment: Maybe it's basically impossible to use WSAStartup() in VS2012? http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.common.internal.nativemethods.wsastartup.aspx

Comment: Surely you need to ask a completely different question. Like, *how can I find the name of the phone?*

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Then it would be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14031025/how-can-i-get-the-device-name-as-defined-in-zune and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616546/wp7-get-phone-name

Comment: So you have your answer then.

Comment: No, see first link of the question. I'm trying to convert C++ code to C#. In the worst case, I'll use a trial version of VS2012 Professional Edition.

Comment: Hard to understand why 2012 would help

Comment: So the issue is Express vs other editions rather than 2012 vs 2013?

Comment: So the issue is Express vs other editions rather than 2012 vs 2013?

Comment: VS2012 didn't help. Andy's solution wasn't applicable for Windows Phone 7, no matter what. I made a false assertion to start with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WSAStartup` [has a SecurityCriticalAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.common.internal.nativemethods.wsastartup.aspx) that makes for internal only, you can't it use from your application.

PInvoke is not allowed for windows phone 7 apps.

Comment: Apparently Andy-Pennell was successful at it in C++ (first link of the question). And it's not exactly an application I'm doing, it's more of a portable library.

Comment: The article clearly mentions it's for Windows Phone 8. There is no C++ runtime component for windows phone 7, also no PInvoke. So I don't see how it would work.

Comment: OK, your last assertion about `PInvoke` is the truth. While in Windows Phone 8 it only takes two words, `PeerFinder.DisplayName`, Andy Pennell's elaborate solution with native code is not applicable for Windows Phone 7 and so mostly useless. -_-'

Comment: @Cœur I know your frustration. Due to the many changes in the APIs between 7, 7.5, 8 and 8.1 it's sometimes quite hard to find the proper API.

Answer (score 0):

WP7 allows C# code, not C++. 
And due C# implementation of sockets, you don't need to call WSAStartup() manually, the system will do that for you automatically.

Comment: Fine. How to call getaddrinfo in C#, then? I need it to get the phone name (like, "My Windows Phone").

Comment: I afraid, phone name is not a thing you can extract via network API at WP7. Once I did such investigations, I found useful the only things like NetworkInterface, NetworkInterfaceInfo and DeviceNetworkInformation